# sudo: /usr/sbin/mkfs.ext4: command not found

Tags: 12.04

Im trying to use this command on the Ubuntu flavor to create a volume

```
sudo: /usr/sbin/mkfs.ext4: command not found
```

but get an error. Command not found..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command is located in `/sbin`, not `/usr/sbin`:

```
$ which mkfs.ext4
/sbin/mkfs.ext4
```